# Having trouble acquiring instances using SPARQL queries on Protege

Tags: sparql, protege

I'm having trouble acquiring instances from a subclass on Protege using SPARQL. The task is to create an ontology using information from a Website. To start this I have tried to get the contact information such as the Email addresses and Phone Numbers. I have provided screenshots of the Classes and Individual Tabs below:

[Classes Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2O5A.png)

[Individual Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ0k1.png)

However when I try making my own SPARQL Queries I get nothing, the majority of queries I have done in tasks before have Prefixes but this one doesn't.  Here is the code I've tried:

SELECT ?email
WHERE{
?email rdf:type "Contact_Email".
}

I want it to display a list of the two email addresses.

Can anyone help me fix my code?

Comment: `"Contact_Email"` is not a class URI but a String literal. Use the class URI instead and it works

Comment: not that I understand why email is a class in your ontology ... why is it not just a data property and maps to a email string instead? Same for phone number. Those are not real world entities, it's quite unusual to model such data as individuals.

Comment: @UninformedUser how do I enter the line using the class URI? I'm sorry, I'm really stuck on this

Comment: just use the URI and put it into `<>`, i.e. `SELECT ?email WHERE{ ?email rdf:type <YOUR_FULL_EMAIL_CLASS_URI_HERE>. }`

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks very much! That got it